# Show that the $x_\delta$ is asymptotically stable of the following system ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the following nonlinear system of ODE
$$
x'(t)=f(x(t))+\delta g(x(t)), x\in R^N
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are two smooth vector fields and $\delta$ is a parameter. Suppose that as $\delta=0$, the system has a hyperbolic and asymptotically stable equilibrium $x_0$. That means eigenvalues of its linearization have negative real parts. Show that the equilibrium $x_\delta$ near $x_0$ is asymptotically stable by **quadratic Lyapunov function** if $\delta$ is small enough.

---

*My attempt:*

Based on the @copper.hat's answer, I edited my previous answer as follows.
Define $$\phi(\delta, x):=f(x)+\delta g(x) $$
and define $y=x-x_\delta$.

Let $$y'=\frac{\partial \phi(x_\delta)}{\partial x} y=: Ay$$be the linearization of the the system $x'=\phi(\delta, x)$. And assume that
$$
\phi(\delta, x)=Ay+h(y),
$$
where $|h(y)|=o(|y|)$.

Since all eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real part **[Question: why does this one hold?]**, then there exists a positive definite matrix  $B$ so that $A^TB+BA+I=0$. Consider
$$
V(x)=y^TBy
$$

Then
$$
\dot{V}(x)=(x'-x'_\delta)^TB(x-x_\delta)+(x-x_\delta)^TB(x'-x'_\delta)
$$
$$
=((x-x_\delta)^TA^T+h^T(x-x_\delta))B(x-x_\delta)+(x-x_\delta)^TB(A(x-x_\delta)+h)
$$
$$
=(x-x_\delta)^T(-I)(x-x_\delta)+2(x-x_\delta)^TBh(x-x_\delta)
$$
$$
<-\|x-x_\delta\|^2+2\gamma\|B\|\|x-x_\delta\|^2=-(1+2\gamma \|B\|)\|x-x_\delta\|^2
$$
where we assume that for any $\gamma>0$, there is $r>0$ so that $\|x-x_\delta\|<r$ we have
$$
|h(x-x_\delta)|\le \gamma\|x-x_\delta\|
$$

Thus, we choose $\gamma< \frac{1}{2\gamma \|B\|}$, then as $\|x-x_\delta\|<r$
$$
\dot{V}(x)<0
$$

Comment: You need to be careful above. You have $f(x) \approx A(x-x_0)+h(x-x_0)$. You can't assume that the expansion about $x_\delta$ is the same (it is close, but not the same).

Comment: It is not clear to me that you can use a single Lyapunov function to solve the problem.

Comment: My answer below shows that for small $\delta$ the eigenvalues of the linearisation about $x_\delta$ have all negative real parts. Hence there exists a $B_\delta$ such that...

Comment: $V_\delta(x) = (x-x_\delta)^T B_\delta (x-x_\delta)$.

Comment: The linearisation of the perturbed system is $y'=({\partial f(x_\delta) \over \partial x} + \delta {\partial g(x_\delta) \over \partial x} )y $. Other than increasing the chance of a mistake, there is no point in setting $x_\delta = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to establish asymptotic stability, it would be simpler to note that the implicit function theorem with $\phi(\delta,x) = f(x)+ \delta g(x)$ shows that for small $\delta$ the perturbed system has an equilibrium point $x_\delta$, and $\lim_{\delta \to 0} x_\delta = x_0$. By continuity, for small(er) $\delta$, the eigenvalues of ${\partial \phi(\delta, x_\delta) \over \partial x}$ also have negative real parts and hence is asymptotically stable.

Comment: The question changed since I answered it.

Comment: Are you trying to find a single Lyapunov function for all perturbations in a ball??? If not, for each small $\delta $ you can find a B_\delta$ that works.

Comment: You are not answering my question. For each $\delta$ you can find a Lyapunov function that works. I am asking if you want a single Lyapunov that works for all (suitably small) $\delta$.

Comment: Can you please see my update answer? Also, I have one more question, why for small $\delta$, the eigenvalues of $\partial \phi/\partial x$ also have negative real parts? I did not see why this one follows from the continuity of $\phi$?