# How to show this perturbed matrix also has negative real parts for $\delta$ small enough

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Based on this question:[Show that the $x_\delta$ is asymptotically stable of the following system ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4801352/show-that-the-x-delta-is-asymptotically-stable-of-the-following-system-ode).

> Consider the following nonlinear system of ODE
> $$
> x'(t)=f(x(t))+\delta g(x(t)), x\in R^N
> $$
> where $f$ and $g$ are two smooth vector fields and $\delta$ is a parameter. Suppose that as $\delta=0$, the system has a hyperbolic and asymptotically stable equilibrium $x_0$. That means eigenvalues of its linearization have negative real parts.

By implicit function theorem with $\phi(\delta,x) = f(x)+ \delta g(x)$ shows that for small $\delta$ the perturbed system has an equilibrium point $x_\delta$, and $\lim_{\delta \to 0} x_\delta = x_0$.

**Show that for small(er) $\delta$, the eigenvalues of $A_\delta:={\partial \phi(\delta, x_\delta) \over \partial x}$ also have negative real parts.**

---

I am confused about how to show this perturbed matrix also has negative real parts for $\delta$ small enough.

We know that as $\delta=0$, the matrix $$A=\lim_{\delta\to 0}A_\delta=\frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x}$$
has negative real parts.

It seems one problem from Linear algebra...

Comment: Somewhat intuitively, the eigenvalues are continuous in function of the matrix (because the roots of a polynomial vary continuously as a function of the coefficients), and the matrix is continuous (around $\delta \to 0$) as a function of $\delta$. So since $A_{\delta = 0}$ has eigenvalues with negative real parts, we can find a tiny $\mu > 0$ so $A_{\delta}$ has eigenvalues with negative real parts, for $|\delta| < \mu$ small. (Complex numbers with negative real part are an open subset of the complex plane!)

Comment: @NeckverseHerdman Thanks! But why can we find such $\mu>0$ so that $A_\delta$ has eigenvalues with negative real parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to show that having eigenvalues with a negative real part is an open condition i.e. if $A$ has eigenvalues all with negative real part, then any $B$ close enough to $A$ verifies the same property. Then, you can conclude by using the convergence of $A_\delta$ toward $A$.

There are several ways to show it. One of them is to notice that the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ vary continuously with $A$ and the roots of a given polynomial of constant degree and dominant coefficient vary continuously too. However, we have to define the topology on the set of roots, and there is a faster "hand made" method.

Reason by contradiction and assume there is a sequence $B_n \rightarrow A$ such that for all $n$, $B_n$ has an eigenvalue $\mu_n$ such that $\Re(\mu_n) \geqslant 0$ and set $v_n$ an associated eigenvector. Up to normalising it, we may assume $\|v_n\| = 1$. The unit sphere in finite dimension is compact thus, up to an extraction, the sequence $(v_n)$ converges toward some limit $v$ of norm $1$.

For all $n$, $B_nv_n = \mu_nv_n$ and $B_nv_n \rightarrow Av$ hence $\mu_nv_n \rightarrow Av$. Let $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$ be such that $v(k) \neq 0$ ($v(k)$ is the $k$th coefficient of $v$). It exists because $v \neq 0$. We have $\mu_nv_n(k) \sim \mu_nv(k) \rightarrow (Av)(k)$ so $\mu_n \rightarrow \frac{(Av)(k)}{v(k)}$. Let us call $\mu$ this limit. $\mu_n \rightarrow \mu$ implies that $\mu_nv_n \rightarrow \mu v = Av$.

$\mu$ is an eignevalue of $A$ so $\Re(\mu) < 0$ but $\Re(\mu_n) \geqslant 0$ for all $n$, which is a contradiction. It proves the wanted result.

Comment: Thank you! But I have few questions about your proof. (1)Here you choose $B_n=A+\delta B$, where $B=Dg(x)$? (2) Do you mean $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|B_n-A\|=0$? (3) What do you mean $\mu_n v_n(k)\sim \mu_nv(k)$? (4) Why $R(\mu)<0$? (5) Why do you say $B_n\to A$ for all $n$? It seems that holds for $n$ large enough.

Comment: (1) and (2) $(B_n)$ is any sequence of matrices that converge toward $A$ (in the sens that $\|B_n - A\| \rightarrow 0$). The purpose is to show that the set of matrices whose eigenvalues all have a negative real part is open by contradiction. And if this set is not open, its complement is not close thus there exists a sequence $B_n \rightarrow A$ with for all $n$, $B_n$ have an eignevalue with a non negative real part. (3) It means that there exists a sequence $w_n \rightarrow 1$ such that $\mu_nv_n(k) = w_n\mu_n v(k)$.

Comment: (4) Because $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. (5) I mean $B_n \rightarrow A$ when $n \rightarrow +\infty$ in the sens $\|B_n - A\| \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow +\infty$.